# Adding custom object to ArrayList already saved in sharedpreference

Tags: sharedpreferences, android-mediaplayer, android-sharedpreferences, android-music-player, audio-player

I'm trying to implement "Recently Played" playlist in my music player that shows those songs which were played by user recently(in a recyclerView). But what I code does is, it only stores the last played song.

What I want: If I have 2 songs in my music player say, A and B. I played song A first. Then it should be added to recently played list(at first position). After that if I play song B, it also should be added to list(not replacing A)but pushing A down and B occupying first position. So the final list should look like : B on the top and A below it.

What my app does: If I play song A first and then song B and after playing both if I go to recently played list, I can see both the songs there. If I play song A first and go to recently played list it is there and after coming back I play song B and then go to recently played list it only shows song B. In the latter case, both should be seen, but it is not. I think a new array is being created every time.

Code:

```
public void storeAudioPlaylist(SongInfoModel songInfoModel) {
preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(STORAGE, 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
playlistStore.add(songInfoModel);
String json = gson.toJson(playlistStore);
editor.putString("audioPlayList", json);
editor.apply();
}

 public ArrayList<SongInfoModel> loadAudioPlaylist() {
preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(STORAGE, 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = preferences.getString("audioPlayList", null);
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<SongInfoModel>>() {
}.getType();
return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

The above 2 functions are used for storing song object to array and retrieving the array respectively.

Code :

```
  public void onClickListener(SongInfoModel song, int position) {

storageUtil.storeAudioPlaylist(song); // this calls the method and passes 
                                     the song model(ID,name,artist..etc)


 }
```